# MS Edge wrong display a slideshow and a content below

Tags: css, slideshow, microsoft-edge

I'm creating a simple site here: http://dev.bajan.sk/poplar/en/ubytovna-poplar
The problem is only in MS Edge, there is a slideshow above the page content. In each other browser, which I tried, the content is below the slider, but in Edge it seems, like the slideshow would by position:absolute, or fixed. I checked a custom CSS, but there's nothing to repair. 
My problem is, that I use win7, so it's impossible to install the Edge. I was using only browserstack.com account, but the free halfhour passed away and it's also very very slowly. If someone could help, I would be thankful.

Comment: Your site link display 404 error on my side. Can you post the enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT sory, I repaired the wrong link. The problem is only in EDGE browser... here's the correct link again: http://dev.bajan.sk/poplar/en/ubytovna-cerveny-kutik/

Comment: @MegoSoft The site requires questions about code not working be self-contained; they need to include an MCVE (see Zhi's comment above) *in the question itself*. SO questions have a feature called a Stack Snippet that lets you run code just like JSFiddle or CodePen. This requirement is to prevent linkrot for when you fix your live site or when it goes offline.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. 
This site was not created by me from scratch. I only took a job after a graphic designer, who played on coder. He didn't upgrade the plugins, which means, the very old version of bootstrap (from year 2014) was linked to site. The Edge browser has a problem. Two clicks to update the plugins and everything work fine now.